# how to predefine a Vector[Tuple] as function argument where the tuple has unknown length

Tags: scala, tuples

With Scala 2.12, I created a function to write `vecInpu: Vector[Tuple]`, where this tuple has unknown length, into a csv file.

```
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}

  def wriCSV(vecInpu:**Vector[(Any)]**, strPath: String,strFileName:String): Unit = {
   val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(strPath + "\\" + strFileName + ".csv"))

    vecInpu.map{a=>writer.write(a.**productIterator**.mkString("@,@")+"\n")}
    writer.close()
  }
```

This `vecInpu.map{a=>writer.write(a.productIterator.mkString("@,@")+"\n")}` worked with an example, but I don't know how to predefine it as an input into function wriCSV. `Vector[(Any)]` does not work with productIterator.

Comment: Rather than using `Any`, use `wriCSV[T<:Product](vecInput: Vector[T] ...)`. But `productIterator` works on any subclass of `Product` so why the restriction to only Tuples? It is probably worth looking at why this is needed in the first place, as it implies some design issues.

Comment: Thanks, I use Vector[Tuple] because there will be different types of elements in the inner collections and productIterator is the only method I cound find for this task. Let me know if you have a better solution.

Comment: @Tim, if you can answer the question in a different post, I can accept it